# How to handle full width with StencilJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, stenciljs

Let's assume we have a very simple component as below

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'custom-button',
})
export class CustomButton {
  render() {
    return <button class={{ 'button--blue': true }}>Press Me</button>
  }
}
```

The component above will render as below on the DOM tree

```html
<custom-button class="hydrated">
  <button class="button--blue">Press Me</button>
</custom-button>
```

Now everything is working fine. The problem comes only if we define `width: 100%` in `button--blue` class. It will not work because `width: 100%` of `custom-button` is essentially pointless.

I know we can solve the problem by using `Host` element and applying css on it

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'custom-button',
})
export class CustomButton {
  render() {
    return (
      <Host class={{ 'full-width': true }}><button class={{ 'button--blue': true }}>Press Me</button></Host>
    )
  }
}
```

I am looking for alternative solution, reason being we need to purposely create another generic utility css class just because we are using `stencil` which I feel its not optimal.

Ultimately it will be great if my CSS is not polluted and I only have `button--blue` class.

Wondering if there is any alternatives available? Maybe somehow we can omit `custom-button` element when we render to the DOM tree?

Comment: Not sure why you don't just apply `class="button--blue` to the host? Alternatively you could try `display: contents` on the host but it's not fully supported yet (https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents#:~:text=display%3A%20contents%20causes%20an%20element's,grid%20or%20similar%20layout%20techniques.).

Comment: @SimonHänisch: `button--blue` is just a concept, it could be using `flex` and changing the layout, if we are applying to `Host`, the layout will be having an issue then